# java.util.Random peculiarity

Tags: java, random, linux-mint

So here is one of the simplest things one might do:

```
Random rng = new Random();
int a = rng.nextInt(10);
int b = rng.nextInt(10);
```

So far so good. But we want to avoid having equal a and b, so naturally we do:

```
Random rng = new Random();
int a = rng.nextInt(10);
int b = rng.nextInt(10);
while (a == b){
  b = rng.nextInt(10);
}
```

However — to my very very very big surprise — the while loop *never* exits. Never.

I understand that, in theory, with random numbers you *could* have an infinite sequence of one number. But I've had this code running for 10 minutes now and it hasn't exited the loop.

What's up with this? I'm running JDK 6 Update 16 on the latest Linux Mint.

Comment: Weird. Did you try to initialize Random with a seed? Random r = new Random( 19580427 );

Comment: Works as expected for me. Java 1.6 u17. Post a complete class, including imports, that reproduces the problem.

Comment: That basiacally is the complete code. It just returns a and b as a char array after that. The only thing that could be causing this might be, that the method is static. Wait, I'll try.

Comment: Just a minor notice: I'd change the line `int b = rng.nextInt(10)` to `int b;` and turn the `while(a==b) {}` into `do {} while (a!=b)` so you have to call `b = rng.nextInt(10)` just once - won't change anything, but is "better" code.

Comment: Works fine on Ubuntu 9.10 with Java 6u16

Comment: How you know the loop doesn't exit? The complete code would be a help...

Comment: @schnaader, `while () {}` is preferred over `do {} while ();` in coding standards sometimes because the condition is always checked.

Comment: Also, you should *never* reduce your entropy pool by kicking out random numbers you don’t like. This way you will end with *less* entropy. The same number twice in a row is perfectly valid and random. Just use it as is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    Random rng = new Random();
    int a = rng.nextInt(10);
    int b = rng.nextInt(9);
    if (b >= a) ++b;
```

Problem solved!

Comment: should'nt it be `if (b == a)` ?

Comment: No. If you did that you'd get a+1 twice as often as the other numbers.

Comment: No, because then you lose the possibility of picking 9, and you double the probability of `a+1`. We are removing a from the set of possibilities for b by shifting [a+1,10) down 1, to remove the hole left by a.

Comment: Also, +1 for a deterministic way of doing this.

Comment: Carlos, that will make b's value equal (a+1) twice as likely as other values. 
An even quicker one probably is: if(b==a) b=9;

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why this would be happening -- I tried it in 1.6.0_16 for Windows and had no problems.  Here's the complete class:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rng = new Random();
        int a = rng.nextInt(10);
        int b = rng.nextInt(10);
        while (a == b){
            System.out.println(b + " is equal to " + a + "!");
            b = rng.nextInt(10);
        }
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Sometimes I'll get the "a is equal to b!" output once or twice in a row, but then it works after that.

Comment: So the fail is in whatever thing Linux Mint is

Comment: RocketSurgeon: Look at the code for java.util.Random(). I severely doubt that there are any OS dependencies that might change the result.

Comment: +1 - Based on this evidence, it looks like the "Linux Mint" packages for Java are broken and should not be trusted.

Answer (score 1):

Practically, it should work. Something wrong with your environment.

However, **theoretically**, we can't predict what random is; it is legit if a random generator gives you the same number one million times in a row. To have a deterministic code, you can do this:

```
int a = rng.nextInt(10);
int b = rng.nextInt( 9);
b = (a+b+1)%10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try setting the seed to something else to see if that helps.

rng.setSeed(123456);